# Select rows with same id but different value in another column - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that shows the chain of custody of a piece of evidence as it is being analyzed. The evidence may just be analyzed at one location, but can also be transferred to different labs to be analyzed. I am trying to write a query that returns the Case Number if it is analyzed in different labs.

Here is an example of the data: CaseNumber 1 starts off in the Chemistry Lab, then transferred to DNA lab, then transferred back to Chemistry Lab. Case 2 is just associated in the Chem lab (do not need to see this case in the query results).

```
ID   CaseNumber     Lab        ActionDate   Action
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1     1             Chem       1/1/2019     case created
2     1             Chem       1/2/2019     container created
3     1             DNA        2/1/2019     container routed to DNA
4     1             DNA        2/3/2019     evidence analyzed
5     1             Chem       2/3/2019     edit route
6     2             Chem       2/4/2019     create case
7     2             Chem       2/5/2019     analyze evidence
```

Here is what I have so far.  This returns casenumber and unique lab but I would like to incorporate the ActionDate somehow to show the actual date it was routed to the new location.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    casenumber, lab 
FROM 
    summary 
WHERE 
    casenumber IN (SELECT a.casenumber 
                   FROM summary a
                   JOIN summary b on b.casenumber = a.casenumber AND b.lab <> a.lab)
    AND actiondate BETWEEN '2019-01-02' AND '2019-01-04'
ORDER BY
    casenumber
```

I expect the results of the query to look like the following. I would like to see the first entry per Lab (since that is the date it was actually routed to the new location)

```
ID   CaseNumber     Lab        ActionDate   Action
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1     1              Chem       1/1/2019    case created
3     1              DNA        2/1/2019    container routed to DNA
5     1              Chem       2/3/2019    container routed to Chem
```

Comment: Not sure why this received a downvote. They posted sample data, desired output and an explanation of what they expect right alongside their attempt. It has all the things people are looking for in a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to accomplish this, here is one of them.  Note this will only work on sql server 2012+.

```
create table #Something
(
    ID int
    , CaseNumber int
    , Lab varchar(10)
    , ActionDate date
    , Action varchar(50)
)

insert #Something values
(1, 1, 'Chem', '1/1/2019', 'case created')
, (2, 1, 'Chem', '1/2/2019', 'container created')
, (3, 1, 'DNA', '2/1/2019', 'container routed to DNA')
, (4, 1, 'DNA', '2/3/2019', 'evidence analyzed')
, (5, 1, 'Chem', '2/3/2019', 'edit route')
, (6, 2, 'Chem', '2/4/2019', 'create case')
, (7, 2, 'Chem', '2/5/2019', 'analyze evidence')
;

with SortedResults as
(
    select s.ID
        , s.CaseNumber
        , s.Lab
        , s.ActionDate
        , Action = case when LAG(Lab, 1) over(partition by CaseNumber order by ActionDate) is null then Action 
            when LAG(Lab, 1) over(partition by CaseNumber order by ActionDate) = Lab then NULL
            else 'container routed to ' + Lab end
    from #Something s
)

select *
from SortedResults
where Action > ''
order by CaseNumber, ActionDate

drop table #Something
```

Comment: Good Morning Sean. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  After looking through your code and understanding it, is it possible to generate the results without taking the Action column into consideration.  I went through the actual data, and at the time the case is transferred to the other Lab, in the action description, there are multiple crazy descriptions in there.  Can I somehow just get the the results to show that Casenumber 1 was first at the Chem lab on 1/1/2019, then it got transferred to DNA lab on date 2/1/2019, then got transferred again on 2/3/2019.  Thanks again.

Comment: @zephyr223 I don't understand what you mean. You could just remove that column in the select statement.